# VisNetwork: nodesIdSelection argument in VisOptions does not behave similarly to selectNode argument in visEvents

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, visnetwork

I am having a hard time figuring out why in [VisNetwork](https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/), the `nodesIdSelection` argument in `VisOptions` does not behave similarly to the `selectNode` argument in `visEvents`.

Basically, when I click on any node, the R console returns as expected "The selected node ID is: X" but when I select the node from the dropdown list (generated with visOptions) then the message is not issued in the console.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(visNetwork)
ui <- fluidPage(
  visNetworkOutput('network')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  getDiagramPlot <- function(nodes, edges){
    v <- visNetwork(
      nodes,
      edges
    ) %>%
      visPhysics(stabilization = TRUE, enabled = TRUE) %>%
      visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = T, degree = 1, hover = F),
                 nodesIdSelection = list(enabled = TRUE, main = "Select ID"),
                 autoResize = TRUE, collapse = FALSE) %>%
      visEdges(color = list(highlight = "red")) %>% # The colour of the edge linking nodes
      visLayout(improvedLayout = TRUE) %>%
      visEdges(arrows = edges$arrows) %>%
      visInteraction(multiselect = F) %>%
      visEvents(selectNode = "function(nodes) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
            ;}")
    return(v)
  }

  testFunction <- function(node_id){
    print(paste("The selected node ID is:", node_id))
  }

  nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label = 1:3)
  edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork(
    getDiagramPlot(nodes, edges)
  )

  observeEvent(input$current_node_id,{
    testFunction(input$current_node_id)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to pass the same javascript code in `visEvents` to `nodesIdSelection`?

Best,

C.

I tried to pass the javascript code from visEvents:

```
"function(nodes) {
            Shiny.onInputChange('current_node_id', nodes.nodes);
            ;}"
```

to the `style` HTML argument (in `nodesIdSelection`) but this had not effect.

Comment: The reason is Shiny event `current_node_id` is only updated by a mouse click, but at the moment I don't know how to fix it.